# retrieve Quote - 404 Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am working in MS CMS 2011 and try to retrieve a quote with an id in javascript.

```javascript
var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();            
id = id.replace('{','').replace('}','');
var options = "$select=" + ebcont.crm.meta.quote.QuoteNumber
  + "&$filter=" + ebcont.crm.meta.quote.QuoteId + " eq (guid'" + id +"')";
SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords(
  ebcont.crm.meta.quote.LogicalName, 
  options, 
  ebcont.crm.quote._successRetrieve,
  function(error) { alert(error.message); }, 
  ebcont.crm.quote._retrieveQuoteComplete);
```

I got following error message:

> Error: 404: Not Found: resource for segment 'quoteSet' not found.

I have used them same way to retrieve a country and there was no problem. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In addition to @JamesWood - did you check the actual value of *id*? Is it conceivable that it's *null*? Can you query other objects, besides *country*? Can you manually query for quotes? Also, I'm not at my computer right now so it's a guess - what do you get if you intentionally misspell the entity name? Is it 404 or some other error code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the ODATA calls can be quite picky around casing.

Try changing `ebcont.crm.meta.quote.LogicalName` to `Quote`.

As a side the `Set` bit is appened by the SDK code (assuming you are using the same example of the MSDN that I have).

Comment: I'd up vote you five times if I could. It is VERY picky about case.